# Using an IF statement, in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

```
For Each cel In rng.Cells

'cel.Select
'If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value > ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value Then
'If cel.Offset(0, -1).Value > cel.Offset(0, 9).Value Then
    cel.Value = "YES"
    Else
    cel.Value = "NO"
    End If
    
I = I + 1

Next cel
On Error Resume Next
```

[image]

Afternoon all. I have the above code in my VBA which runs through a preset range (brown column) and checks whether the time last closed is larger than the calc column and then changes the cell value between them to a "Yes".

I've tried both IF statements, and the code seems to run without error, but I'm not actually seeing any result? Just wondering if I've gone the wrong wway about it?

PS. The Calc column is offset by 9 in the spreadsheet :)

Comment: Check that your time cells **only** contain the time, and aren't actually holding the date as well but not displaying it.

Comment: The lefthand column does have the date, will have to look at removing it, and the hand hand column is a sum - =SUM(E***+5/1440) (E being another time in a seperate column)

Comment: Formula shouldn't cause an issue when using value. Your second If worked for me (I manually entered the times so there's no date behind it) and when editing two cells in "Time last closed" to values higher than the Calc ones, I did get a yes in the proper cells.

Comment: So just for clarify the values of the cells in the lefthand column are the result of a vlookup formula, and the values in the right hand cells are the result of a SUM formula (just needed 5 minutes adding onto another time column)

Comment: Er, If you do not mind me asking... Why VBA and not a simple Excel formula?

Comment: Also if you want to use VBA then you do not need a Loop. You can use VBA to enter a formula in the entire range in one go and then change it to value using 'rng.Value = rng.Value'

Comment: Why don't you share the complete code from `Sub...` to at least `...Next cel`, preferably to `...End Sub`? How could we know that you haven't set the range wrong? Or selected the wrong worksheet? Also, remove any `On Error Resume Next` because it is hiding what is really going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing just the time elements of both cells:

```
If text(cel.Offset(0, -1).Value,"hh:mm") > text(cel.Offset(0, 0).Value,"hh:mm") Then
  cel.Value = "YES"
Else
  cel.Value = "NO"
End If
```